# Step to create report with parameters (RDLC)

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, tableadapter

What are the basic steps to create reports in Visual Studio 2013 with parameters ?

I'm planning on having a single reportviewer that I would use to load all .rdlc reports from code and follow this approach:

1. Create a single form with a ReportViewer in it.
2. Create a dataset.
3. Create a tableAdapter with the query needed.
4. Create the report.
5. Load the report from code.

What is not clear to me is how to create the report if the query I'm using has parameters that will be passed only later in the code and if it's possibile to use just one reportViewer to load different reports.